# fixed position inside visible area of parent div

Tags: html, css, position

I'm wondering if there is a way to fix an element inside a visible area of the `div` as I've described in the image below.

[image: Position of fixed element inside div]

Here is an example of my problem ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5Lb6qyw/6/)):

HTML:

```
<div id="header" ></div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a id="menu-collapse">collapse</a>
        <div id="some-block"></div>
    </div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 134, 27);
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(27, 48, 0);
    min-width: 540px;
}

#menu-collapse{

}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(27, 118, 0);
}

#some-block{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 2500px;
}
```

I need to have `#menu-collapse` in the middle of the visible area of `#menu`, while scrolling `#menu`.

Comment: If you want more specific information that the two answers you've received, you should include your CSS and HTML code.

Comment: I just did thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` in your CSS class definition. This will position the div relative to the browser window instead of the document itself, allowing it to maintain its position as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to fix the element inside a div area if you use `position:fixed;` property then it will automatically fix it relatively to the browser.

Its a default feature.

Answer (score 0):

On `#menu-collapse`, you need to add `position: fixed;` to get it to stay in the same position. And, you need `top: 50%;` in order to have it in the middle of `#menu`, and `z-index: 1;` in order for it to display on top of `#some-block`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5Lb6qyw/8/)

HTML:

```
<div id="header" ></div>
<div id="menu">
    <a id="menu-collapse">collapse</a>
    <div id="some-block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae tortor fermentum, pellentesque lorem vitae, ullamcorper urna. Sed in imperdiet nisl, porta porta sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum euismod sapien a imperdiet placerat. Ut a maximus felis. Mauris porta purus id mi feugiat ultrices. Etiam mattis leo id hendrerit sagittis. Vivamus dapibus blandit ligula varius semper.</p>
        <p>Ut nisl neque, efficitur non risus vitae, luctus cursus dui. Pellentesque aliquam varius cursus. Fusce lobortis, sapien at dictum porta, erat eros rhoncus metus, sit amet finibus libero quam nec nisl. Phasellus tempus ante vitae rutrum ultricies. Fusce sit amet hendrerit quam, egestas gravida risus. Donec eget tristique enim, ac lacinia nunc. Nam pulvinar, nunc et scelerisque ornare, est augue mollis sem, vel vulputate arcu mi et eros. Proin varius arcu vitae nisi porttitor, sit amet finibus eros congue. In dapibus tincidunt tortor. Sed at sem id tortor molestie finibus eget ut sem. In semper feugiat elementum. Morbi enim mauris, venenatis non felis ac, interdum euismod sapien. Praesent semper ante vel mauris auctor, ut commodo ipsum malesuada. Morbi hendrerit tortor sapien. Nulla in hendrerit dui, eu accumsan est</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 134, 27);
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(27, 48, 0);
    min-width: 540px;
}

#menu-collapse{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(27, 118, 0);
}

#some-block{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 2500px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but #menu-collapse is not in the middle of #menu but in the middle relative to whole page. You can see that when I set #menu  top: 170px; it's no way near the middle.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm not sure that there's a way. I Googled around to see if I could find anything, but found nothing that worked for your scenario... It might be that using JS to find the height of `#menu`, and then using that to position `#menu-collapse` might be your only option...